# Problema ao se conectar a BeagleBone Black

Tags: linux

Alguém sabe como se conectar a `BeagleBone Black` ? O Linux que tinha nela era muito antigo, então resolvi fazer um novo boot e instalar um Linux mais recente que foi o `debian-9.1-console-armhf-2017-09-21` do repositório `https://rcn-ee.com/rootfs` . Antes de dar o boot na placa eu descomento a linha :

```
cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh
```

Do arquivo `uEven.txt` da pasta boot.

O boot ocorre perfeitamente, contudo quando a placa desliga ao final do processo e ligo-a novamente aparece 2 IPs um é o `192.168.6.1` e o outro é `192.168.7.1`, não aparece mais o `192.168.7.2` que aparecia com o Linux antigo.

No arquivo   `user_password.list` desse Linux tem : `debian:temppwd` ou seja, para se conectar a placa o servidor é o `debian` e a senha é `temppwd` ccontudo quando faço :

```
sudo ssh debian@192.168.6.1
```

E uso a senha `temppwd`, não se conecta diz  : `Permission denied, please try again.`

Tentei me conectar usando o outro IP mas também não funciona.

O que sai do ifconfig referente a placa é :

```
 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:5f:b8:fe:4f:91  
          inet addr:192.168.6.1  Bcast:192.168.6.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::f3e4:417:5610:3eb4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10188 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:13687 (13.6 KB)


Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:5f:b8:fe:4f:8e  
          inet addr:192.168.7.1  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::e1c7:3469:96f8:c286/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:92 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10115 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:17693 (17.6 KB)
```

Alguém sabe o que possa ser  isso para conseguir  se conectar a placa ?

Comment: Acredito que isso fuja do escopo definido para o site.